# Hidden mx control that doesn't take up space

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am using 2 mx:html controls, one of them is hidden an it's used by the application to load external data from a page. When it's done loading the application will scrape the information from this hidden html control.

The hidden control does not have to take up any space but setting the width and height to 1 will break the page for some reason.

In the example below I set the hidHTML visible property to false yet it keeps taking up space in the main window.

Is there a way for hidHTML to have a width and height but not take up any space and not be visible?

```
<mx:HTML id="gui" location="main.html" enabled="true" 
    complete="mainComplete(event)"
    paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
<mx:HTML visible="false" x="1" y="1"
    location="http://externalinfo.com"
    id="hidHTML"
    width="250"
    height="100"
    horizontalScrollPolicy="off" 
    verticalScrollPolicy="off"
    enabled="true"
    paddingLeft="0"
    paddingRight="0"
    />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to also set includeInLayput="false" and then the control will then take up no space.